# before внутри элемента

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Необходимо задать `before` к элементу напрямую. Т.е. мы можем сделать так:

```
<option style="background: <?=$color?>" value=""> ... </option>
```

А нужно получить что-то такое:

```
<option style="::before {background: <?=$color?>}" value=""> ... </option>
```

Это необходимо для динамического получения цвета. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: это невозможно.

Comment: Вынести стили в отдельный блок <style>

Comment: связанный вопрос: [CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293280/2881286)

Comment: @Рашен Беар, а внутри `<style>` php код будет работать?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать, если вынести стили для элемента в отдельный блок `<style>` и туда подставлять переменную. Но намного логичнее будет придумать дополнительные классы для элемента и уже им задавать `:before`, а в зависимости от значения переменной просто переключать класс.

Comment: А если цвет генерируется динамически в диапазоне от 0 до 65565?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну тогда первый вариант проканает. Но если они генерятся не динамически то второй таки логичнее